# Php and Mysql query select

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question that I don't know the answer, about mysql and php.

If I have 4 table like :

```
user        |member-of-group    |group          |post       |
============|================================================
user_id     |user_id            |group_id       |post_id    |
user_name   |group_id           |group_name     |post_title |
            |                   |user_id        |group_id   |
            |                   |               |user_id    |
```

member-of-group:

> user_id is member in group_id (example : foo is member of group bar);

group:

> user_id is the one who create group_name and group_id (exmple : alpha
>   create group beta "alpha is admin of beta")

post:

> post_id is a content of group_id and created by user_id (example : abc
>   create content def in group xyz  user_id : abc; post_id: def;
>   group_id: xyz ).

I want to create a page that show all contents that are created in all groups where user is member or user is admin

but I don't know how to do that. I already created the table and created the query for insert update and delete, also select.

Thank You

Comment: Use `join`s in the SQL. `group` also is not a good table name, you will need to use backticks on every usage because it is reserved

Comment: is not what I mean, I already work with mysql, I want to say that how to do that, but chris85 write join s, so he gave me an idea, it's just don't know the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT post.* 
FROM post 
     LEFT JOIN `group` USING (group_id) 
     LEFT JOIN `member-of-group` ON post.group_id = `member-of-group`.group_id 
WHERE post.user_id = `group`.user_id 
   OR post.user_id = `member-of-group`.user_id
```

Comment: You are the BEST Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
it's worked